# Partition Key Caching in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Given a particular **key_cache_size_in_mb** in Cassandra's YAML file, when a cluster is started and we start inserting data, will the key_cache keep on increasing till it reaches the configured size i.e. will it keep all the keys cached till it reaches the configured size for the first time? If yes, what will happen once that size is reached? If no, then what's the algorithm which decides which keys should be cached and which keys should not be cached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a [caffeine cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) with a [size based eviction](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#size-based). The cache will try to evict entries that have not been used recently or very often based on [Window TinyLfu](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Efficiency#window-tinylfu).

Comment: I haven't yet understood exactly how the cache is populated. Say, I start Cassandra nodes for the first time. Then I write some x number of rows. Till this time, I believe, Key Cache will be empty. Now if I execute a query to read all the x rows, since the key cache would have been empty, read will take a lot of time(assuming row cache is disabled). I want to know, how many keys will be stored in the key cache after this. Will it store all the x keys? Basically, if I read a particular row, is it guaranteed that it's key will be present in the cache, when I read the same row, the next time?

Comment: It depends on the query on if the keycache is used or not. a `SELECT *` does not use the keycache since it iterates through the ranges and for each range iterates through the data on a CL of the replicas. If you want to run some tests you can use `nodetool info` to see the keycache statistics. you can use `nodetool invalidatekeycache` to reset and `setcachekeystosave` to try different sizes. Keep in mind for faster warm-up the key cache is saved to disk periodically, so restarting may not mean an empty cache. Caches do not really provide guarantees, they just try to improve it for most cases.